Show that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{(-x)^n}{n(1 + x^n)}$ converges uniformly for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$
I have tried to use abel's test and solve as following
Take sequence ${b_n(x)}$ as $\frac{-1^n}{n}$ which is uniformally convergent by Lebinitz test. Also $\frac{x^n}{x^n+1}$ = $\frac{1+x^n-1}{1+x^n}$ = $1 - \frac{1}{1+x^n}$ but this is not monotonic decreasing for a particular value of $x$. How to proceed further?

@MartinR apologies, the question was for all positive reals

For $x > 0$ and positive integers $n$ let $$f_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{n(1+x^n)} \, .$$
If

$f_1(x) \ge f_2(x) \ge f_3(x) \ge \cdots \ge 0$, and
$f_n(x) \to 0$ uniformly on $\Bbb R^+$

then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent, see for example Uniform convergence of alternating series.
We have $ 0 \le f_n(x) \le \frac 1n$ which proves the uniform convergence to zero. It remains to show that $f_n(x)$ is (weakly) decreasing in $n$ for fixed $x > 0$.
Case 1: $0 < x < 1$: Then
$$
 f_n(x)= \frac 1n \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+x^n}\right)
$$
is decreasing in $n$ because both factors are decreasing in $n$.
Case 2: $x \ge 1$. We have
$$
 f_n(x) = f_n(1) + \int_1^x f_n'(y) \, dy 
 = \frac{1}{2n} + \int_1^x \frac{1}{y} \cdot \frac{y^n}{(1+y^n)^2} \, dy \, . 
$$
It is not difficult to show that for $y \ge 1$ the function $n \mapsto \frac{y^n}{(1+y^n)^2}$ is (weakly) decreasing in $n$, and then the above formula implies that $f_n(x)$ is decreasing in $n$.

I see that you have used Dirichlet's test. However I am not clear for case $x \geq 1$. Why are we resorting to break the function into an integral and then checking the monotonicity of the derivative. Is there a name of this method / where can i read up more on this? Also thank you for taking out the time to answer my question.

@dreamboat: For $0 < x < 1$ or even $0 < x \le 1$  it is immediately apparent that $f_n(x)$ is decreasing in $n$. For $x > 1 $ I found it easier to see that the derivative is decreasing in $n$, and then conclude about the functions themselves. So the only reason to split into these cases is “because it works.” Of course there may be other and perhaps simpler proofs, but that is what I have. (I am not aware that this method has a special name.)

An alternative way to see $f_n(x)$ is decreasing in $n$ is to differentiate with respect to $n.$ If $g(n):=f_n(x)=\tfrac{1}{n(x^{-n}+1)}.$ Then $g’(n)= \tfrac{-1}{(n(x^{-n}+1))^2}(x^{-n}+1+n(-\ln(x)x^{-n})$, So need $h(n):=1+x^n-n\ln(x)>0$. Now $h(1)=1+x-\ln(x)>0$ and $h’(n)=\ln(x)x^n-\ln(x)=\ln(x)(x^n-1)\geq0.$
